# want extract entire node of xml file

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have code like this in vb.net

```
Dim str As String

        Dim xmlText As String = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/reply.xml"))
        Dim doc As New XmlDocument()

        doc.LoadXml(xmlText)



        Dim nsmgr As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns1", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
        Dim root As XmlElement = doc.DocumentElement

        Dim node As XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode("//soapenv:Body", nsmgr)
        Dim s As String = node.InnerXml
```

it works fine for me I am able to extract entire inner xml of soapenv:Body node.But I want to extract sub  child node of soapenv:Body node .

My expression for this is like :

```
 Dim node As XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode("//soapenv:Body/ns1:OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS/ns1:PricedItineraries", nsmgr)
```

but it is extracting nothing . My xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS Version="2.001" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:ns1="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
      <ns1:Success />
        <ns1:PricedItineraries>
        <ns1:PricedItinerary CompositeFlightNumber="S2" CountCompositeFlightNumber="1" FareType="Non-Refundable" InboundSegmentReference="1" MatrixFare="true" Mode="" OriginDestinationRPH="BLRMAAS242336620130329" OutboundSegmentReference="1" Priority="1" RecommendationRPH="1" Refundable="true" ReturnOnly="false" SequenceNumber="1.0" SupplierCode="1AWS">
          <ns1:AirItinerary SupplierSystem="Amadeus">
            <ns1:OriginDestinationOptions>
            <ns1:OriginDestinationOption Duration="00:45:00" FlightID="BLRMAAS24233662013-03-29" MajorityCarrier="S2" ReturnOnly="false" SupplierCode="1AWS" SupplierSystem="Amadeus" UniqueIdentifier="1.0">
                <ns1:FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2013-03-29T20:20:00" CabinCode="Y" DeliveryMethod="Courier" DepartureDateTime="2013-03-29T19:35:00" Duration="00:45:00" FlightNumber="4233" LTD="1AWS" LineNumber="Y" NumberInParty="BLRMAA" RPH="1" ResBookDesigCode="G" TicketType="Physical" ValidConnectionInd="1AWS">
                <ns1:DepartureAirport AirPortName="Bengaluru" CityName="Bangalore" LocationCode="BLR" />
                <ns1:ArrivalAirport AirPortName="Chennai" CityName="Chennai" LocationCode="MAA" Terminal="D" />
                <ns1:OperatingAirline Code="S2" />
                <ns1:BookingClassAvail FareType="RP" ResBookDesigCode="G" ResBookDesigQuantity="7" Status="7" WebFareName="G2SAP30" />
                <ns1:Equipment AirEquipType="739" />
                <ns1:MarketingAirline Code="S2" MatrixCode="66" Name="JetKonnect" YTAirlineCode="77" />
                <ns1:ValidatingCarrier Code="S2" />
              </ns1:FlightSegment>
                <ns1:FormData>
                <ns1:FBC Destination="MAA" FlightNumber="4233" LineNumber="Y" Origin="BLR" SeatToSell="7" WebFareName="G2SAP30" />
                 <ns1:FareDifference>
                  <ns1:TotalFare ADT="2" BaseFare="1140-ADT 570" CHD="0" Cabin="Economy" HostName="railserver" INF="0" Rbd="RP - G -" Tax="TTL-4806">5957</ns1:TotalFare>
                </ns1:FareDifference>
                <ns1:TicketingInfo DeliveryMethod="Courier" TicketTimeLimit="2013-03-05 4:19:00" TicketType="Physical" />
                <ns1:AgentMarkup>
                   <ns1:Airlines>
                          :
                          :
                          :
                          :
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set the wrong namespace URI for `"ns1"` on your `XmlNamespaceManager`. According to the XML document you're trying to parse, it should be:

```
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns1", "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")
```

The prefix `ns1:` is used in both your XML and XPath, but that is fundamentally not important. The important thing is that the prefix you use in your XPath is bound to the correct namespace URI.

You could write your code like this:

```
nsmgr.AddNamespace("zzz", "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")
nsmgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
```

and then the XPath like this:

```
//soap:Body/zzz:OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS/zzz:PricedItineraries"
```

and it will still work, as long as the URI matches that of the elements in the document.

Remember: the prefixes in the document are not important; only the namespace URI is important. You can decide what prefixes you use for an XPath, as long as they are bound to the correct URI for the element you're expecting.

Comment: should i remove other name spaces?

Comment: You should only declare each namespace URI once on the XmlNamespaceManager. I will add more explanation to my answer.

Comment: No effect still getting nothing Ben

Comment: You still need to associate the soapenv prefix with a namespace URI.

Comment: Plz could suggest or show me an example from which i can solve this error....thx for ur help

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're doing, but I've modified the code in the way described and it seems to work fine: https://compilr.com/benbasson/xml-extract-test/main.vb (although worth noting the different file path).

Comment: thankyou so much Ben your code is really working.......Hope to be remain in touch with you in future also ..Plz add me on facebook mubashir_034@yahoo.co.in